# Bootstrap style not working while printing a div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to print a table and save it as pdf. But default bootstrap style not working when I print. I want to print the table as shown in the screen. Below is the code that I have tried. Also please look at the codepen.

I tried using bootstrap with media property 'print', but it doesn't work for me.

[Codepen link here.](https://codepen.io/debarshi-das/pen/oNbBgRY)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>


    <div class="container">
        <div class="row mt-5">
            <div class="col-12" id="printable">
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <thead class="thead-dark">
                        <tr>
                        <th scope="col">#</th>
                        <th scope="col">First</th>
                        <th scope="col">Last</th>
                        <th scope="col">Handle</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                        <th scope="row">1</th>
                        <td>Mark</td>
                        <td>Otto</td>
                        <td>@mdo</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <th scope="row">2</th>
                        <td>Jacob</td>
                        <td>Thornton</td>
                        <td>@fat</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <th scope="row">3</th>
                        <td>Larry</td>
                        <td>the Bird</td>
                        <td>@twitter</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12">
                <button class="btn btn-info" id="printBtn">Print Table</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#printBtn').click(function(){
                var divToPrint=document.getElementById('printable');

                var newWin=window.open('','Print-Window');

                newWin.document.open();

                newWin.document.write('<html><body onload="window.print()">'+divToPrint.innerHTML+'</body></html>');

                newWin.document.close();

                setTimeout(function(){newWin.close();},10);
            });

        })
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `newWin.document.write('<html>` you need to include the bootstrap styles if you want to print with bootstrap styles (and include any other styles as well)

Comment: I have included the bootstrap css link. Now it adds the border, but the background colour is still missing. You can check the codepen.